# how to make sentence in input into ul list of words

Tags: javascript, split, html-lists

I need to have whatever words are entered into this input to be spit out (onclick) in the div as an ordered list of one word on each line/element. 1. How do I tell the function to put the words into the list (I know I have to split them somehow, but I don't know how to do that) 2. How do I get the list into the div after that? Javascript only please. Thanks!

EDIT: started a function, now how do I make it put the splits into the ul and then put that in the div? Also is my var split to get the input of the input box right?

```
<script>
function function1()
{
var split= document.getElementById('theInput').value.split(' ')
var var1 = split[0];
var var2 = split [1];
var var3 = split [2];
}
</script>
<h1 id="header">The document header.</h1>
<img id="theImage" src="http://www.uiowa.edu/homepage/images/dome-wm-mobile.gif">
<p>Value: <input type="text" id="theInput" value="" size=10>
<input type="button" id="theButton" value="click me!" onclick="function1"></p>
<ul id="theList">
<li id="element1">Element 1
<li id="element2">Element 2
<li id="element3">Element 3
</ul>
<div id="theDiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this is what you are looking for

```
function splitText()
{
    var textString = document.getElementById("splitText").value;

    var stringArray = new Array();
    stringArray = textString.split(" ");

    var outputString = "<ul>";
    for (i = 0; i < stringArray.length; i++) {
        outputString += "<li>"+ stringArray[i] + "</li>";
    }
    outputString += "</ul>";
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = outputString;
}
```

Here is the HTML code

```
<input id="splitText" type='text'/>
  <div id='output' style='width:100px;height:100px;border: 1px solid' onclick='splitText()'>
```

Comment: I think this is what I'm trying to do, thanks! How do I get the result output in a div as a list?

Comment: When you click on the box (div) it will out put the result to the div as a list

Comment: Hm I must not be doing it right. does the HTML code part go in the body? Or in the div?

Comment: List will get append to the div. What do you meant by "I must not be doing it right" ?

Answer (score 0):

[**Here you go**](http://jsfiddle.net/SqM2z/)

The markup:

```
<p>Input:<input type="text" id="theInput" value="" size=10>
<input type="button" id="button1" value="click" onclick="function1();"></p>
<ul id="theList">
</ul>
<div id="div1"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function function1() {
    var words = document.getElementById("theInput").value.split(" ");
    console.log(words.length);
    for(var i = 0; i < words.length; ++i) {
        var obj = document.createElement('li');
        obj.id = "list"+i;
        obj.innerHTML = words[i];
        document.getElementById("theList").appendChild(obj);
    }
}
```

A friendly tip: Consider working on your naming convention!